# Does shutting down your windows PC safely eject external drives?

Tags: windows

When shutting down your Windows PC will inserted external USB devices be properly ejected or could shutting down during an important operation cause corruption?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, yes – flushing all unwritten buffers and caches and unmounting filesystems is one of the most important parts of the shutdown process. (In some other OSes that's literally the only thing the shutdown process does.)

This also applies to Windows – shutting down the system will flush all pending writes (if there are any to begin with), and that's the important part of "ejecting" a drive.

---

There is a small exception in Windows 8/10: if the "Fast startup" feature is enabled, the shutdown process becomes part-shutdown part-hibernation. According to the Microsoft [TechNet article](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/15645.windows-8-volume-compatibility-considerations-with-prior-versions-of-windows.aspx), internal drives remain mounted during the hybrid shutdown process, as do external USB drives with the "Optimize for performance" option selected.

So it is possible that *older* Windows versions (WinXP/7) won't fully recognize NTFS disks that haven't been "safely removed" from a newer version (Win8/10) due to format differences, and will *think* that the disk is corrupted. (This applies to portable HDDs, but not to USB sticks.)

But although the article doesn't explicitly say so, the fact that it lists "disable NTFS log upgrade" as an equal workaround to "disable fast startup" strongly implies that all writes *are* still flushed to disk even during hybrid shutdown, which means actual corruption will not occur.

So in conclusion,

- If you have "Fast startup" enabled,
- *and* you have an external portable HDD/SSD drive attached,
- *and* the drive shows up in 'Computer' as a HDD, not as a USB stick,
- *and* the drive is NTFS-formatted,
- *and* the drive is set to "Optimize for performance" in Device Manager,
- *and* you plan on using the drive with WinXP/Vista/7 immediately afterwards,

then you still should eject it before shutdown. But any other drive (USB sticks, FAT32-formatted disks, HDDs with "Optimize for quick removal") will be automatically ejected regardless of "Fast startup" being enabled or not.

Comment: "shutting down during an important operation" this question is too broad as we have no clue what the process is and how windows will terminate it during shut down.

Answer (score 1):

Windows' built-in solution usually works like this. You should  Click the Safely Remove Hardware icon in the notification area and select the drive.